# How to write separators between hyperlinks in HTML

Tags: html

How to have a nav section in html header like this with a separator in between each hyeprlink Home | Admin | Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put a line between links in html navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446595/put-a-line-between-links-in-html-navigation-bar)

Comment: Hi kamali, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this question isn’t suitable for SO because it is asking for a tutorial. New users are recommended to read the [ask] section for guidance on how to ask a good question in SO. Posts are encouraged to contain a [mre] and show the issues that came up while attempting this. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `:before` to set for it content `"|"`.

`:not(:first-child)` will ignore apply `|` before `Home` (first child).

You can see my below demo:

```css
.menu-item:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "|";
  padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu-item" href="#">Home</a> <a class="menu-item" href="#">Admin</a> <a class="menu-item" href="#">Help</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want but I thought you wanted a separator between links on your page
if this is how you have your nav setup:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
</div>
```

Or something similar. You should add in the separator like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <div>|</div>
    <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
    <div>|</div>
    <a href="/help">Help</a>
</div>
```

and give it same/similar css if you have any